# Oracle Datastore + Jboss datasource Connectivity + Connection Refused

Tags: jboss, oracle11g

I am facing a strange issue with connectivity to the Oracle database from Jboss server.

Both the JBoss and Oracle database are installed in my laptop.

When i startup the Jboss when I am connected to my office network then JBoss starts up fine. But when I start my Jboss server at home (not connected to office network) then I am getting below error

```
08:03:17,513 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:179)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:577)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:262)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:500)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:341)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:315)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:396)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:842)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:88)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.cmp.jdbc.SQLUtil.tableExists(SQLUtil.java:1017)
        at org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin.createTableIfNotExists(GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin.java:142)
        at org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.DatabasePersistencePolicy.startService(DatabasePersistencePolicy.java:104)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy42.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.XSLSubDeployer.start(XSLSubDeployer.java:197)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:171)
        ... 121 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
        ... 126 more
```

In the above scenario I have verified the connectivity to the oracle via a standalone JDBC connection via below code and via SQLdeveloper as well (running my laptop).

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/avdb", "avuser", "secret");
```

Below is the snippet of ds file.

```
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>customjndi</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/dbname</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <!-- See login-config.xml for how username and password are set -->
    <max-pool-size>300</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>10000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes> 

    <exception-sorter-class-name>com.custom.jdbc.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>

    <security-domain>EncryptCustomPassword</security-domain>

    <metadata>
        <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

I am using Oracle 11g and Jboss 4.2.2.

**Update:**
Strangely I am facing connection refused error when I tried today. I am getting the same irrespective of whether I am connected to the corporate network or not.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:171)
        ... 121 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
        ... 126 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:201)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)
        ... 131 more
```

Because of the connection refused error I am not getting any entry in the listener.log file.

However, I able to connect to the instance via Java JDBC program or SQLDeveloper.

Any clue???

Comment: Assuming the host name and port has been specified correctly, have a look at the listener.log file.

Comment: @Steve, I revisited this issue today and I am getting connection refused error. There is no entry that corresponds to this request in the listener.log. Why I am getting connection refused error but able to telnet or connect via SQLDeveloper or JDBC Java program?

Comment: Too bad. I found the port 1555 was hardcoded inside the program which caused this issue. Once i remove it worked.